# MATLAB System of Dependent Differential Equations

Tags: matlab, ode

Given a system of differential equations such as:

```
dy/dt = f(t)
dx/dt = g(t)
```

A solution can be found using dsolve, such as:

```
dsolve(diff(y) == f(t), diff(x) == g(t), y(0) == 1, x(0) == 1);
```

But what about a system where all the variables depend on each other:

```
dy/dt = f(y,z)
dx/dt = g(x,y)
dz/dt = h(z,x)
```

When approached in the same way, with initial conditions, for a system which does have a solution, I cannot find a solution.

I know the system I have tried can produce solutions as I have used a stochastic/deterministic simulator - think there's probably some strange syntax to use.

I'm specifically looking for the solution where the derivatives are all zero, if that helps.

EDIT:

Here is an example:

```
PX/dt = (k_tl*(a0_tr + ((a_tr*KM^n)/((KM^n) + (PZ^n))))/kd_mRNA)-kd_prot*PX;
PY/dt = (k_tl*(a0_tr + ((a_tr*KM^n)/((KM^n) + (PX^n))))/kd_mRNA)-kd_prot*PY;
PZ/dt = (k_tl*(a0_tr + ((a_tr*KM^n)/((KM^n) + (PY^n))))/kd_mRNA)-kd_prot*PZ;
```

with the coefficients:

```
eff = 20;

KM = 40;

tau_mRNA=2.0;
tau_prot=10;

ps_a=0.5;
ps_0=5.0E-4;

t_ave = tau_mRNA/log(2);

k_tl=eff/t_ave;

a_tr=(ps_a-ps_0)*60;
a0_tr=ps_0*60;

kd_mRNA = log(2)/tau_mRNA;
kd_prot = log(2)/tau_prot;

beta = tau_mRNA/tau_prot; 
alpha = a_tr*eff*tau_prot/(log(2)*KM);
alpha0 = a0_tr*eff*tau_prot/(log(2)*KM);
n=2;
```

And the initial conditions:

```
PX0 = 20;
PY0 = 0;
PZ0 = 0;
```

This produces a response:

[image: Response]

This clearly has a steady state solution (all derivatives 0).

In MATLAB I have tried:

```
%%
syms PX(t) PY(t) PZ(t);

z = dsolve(diff(PX) == (k_tl*(a0_tr + ((a_tr*KM^n)/((KM^n) + (PZ^n))))/kd_mRNA)-kd_prot*PX, diff(PY) == (k_tl*(a0_tr + ((a_tr*KM^n)/((KM^n) + (PX^n))))/kd_mRNA)-kd_prot*PY, diff(PZ)==(k_tl*(a0_tr + ((a_tr*KM^n)/((KM^n) + (PY^n))))/kd_mRNA)-kd_prot*PZ,PX(0)==20)
```

and:

```
%%
eq1 = (k_tl*(a0_tr + ((a_tr*KM^n)/((KM^n) + (PZ^n))))/kd_mRNA)-kd_prot*PX;
eq2 = (k_tl*(a0_tr + ((a_tr*KM^n)/((KM^n) + (PX^n))))/kd_mRNA)-kd_prot*PY;
eq3 = (k_tl*(a0_tr + ((a_tr*KM^n)/((KM^n) + (PY^n))))/kd_mRNA)-kd_prot*PZ;

dsolve(diff(PX)==eq1,PX(0)==20,diff(PY)==eq2,PY(0)==0,diff(PZ)==eq3,PZ(0)==0)
```

Both produce no errors but return an empty sym.

Comment: "When approached in the same way, with initial conditions, for a system which does have a solution, I cannot find a solution." Are you going to share this system and it's solution with us? When you say "can produce solutions", do you mean the system has analytic solutions or that you've been able to solve it numerically? You need to make your question more concrete. Show your actual code so others can replicate your problem.

Comment: Updated with example.

Answer (score 1):

Your numeric solution appears to have an oscillatory component. The "steady state" may be a zero amplitude limit cycle, which is a non-trivial solution. You definitely shouldn't expect a system like this to have an easy-to-find analytic solution. The cyclic relations between your three variables also doesn't help. For what it's worth, Mathematica 10's `DSolve` also is unable to find a solution.

Though it won't get you to a solution, the way you're using symbolic math is less than optimal. When you use something like `log(2)` in a symbolic math equation, `2` should be converted to a symbolic value first. For example, `sym(log(2))` yields the approximation `6243314768165359/9007199254740992`, whereas `log(sym(2))` returns the exact `log(2)`. This latter form is much more likely to lead to solutions if they exist. Here's a modified version of your code, which unfortunately still returns "Warning: Explicit solution could not be found":

```
eff = 20;

KM = 40;

tau_mRNA=2;
tau_prot=10;

ps_a=1/sym(2);
ps_0=5/sym(10000);

ln2 = log(sym(2));
t_ave = tau_mRNA/ln2;

k_tl=eff/t_ave;

a_tr=(ps_a-ps_0)*60;
a0_tr=ps_0*60;

kd_mRNA = ln2/tau_mRNA;
kd_prot = ln2/tau_prot;

beta = tau_mRNA/tau_prot; 
alpha = a_tr*eff*tau_prot/(ln2*KM);
alpha0 = a0_tr*eff*tau_prot/(ln2*KM);
n=2;

PX0 = 20;
PY0 = 0;
PZ0 = 0;

syms PX(t) PY(t) PZ(t);

eq1 = (k_tl*(a0_tr + a_tr*KM^n/(KM^n + PZ^n))/kd_mRNA)-kd_prot*PX;
eq2 = (k_tl*(a0_tr + a_tr*KM^n/(KM^n + PX^n))/kd_mRNA)-kd_prot*PY;
eq3 = (k_tl*(a0_tr + a_tr*KM^n/(KM^n + PY^n))/kd_mRNA)-kd_prot*PZ;

s = dsolve(diff(PX,t)==eq1,diff(PY,t)==eq2,diff(PZ,t)==eq3,PX(0)==20,PY(0)==0,PZ(0)==0)
```

Comment: I can get numerical solutions which are complex and a bit crazy. This implies that the system never truly stops oscillating and so I should just read off the graph I posted for the steady state value? A further question is.. Can I still produce a Jacobian matrix without being able to solve this, and can I evaluate it at a point I read off the graph? I think that might be the only way to characterise the system

Comment: @user2290362: You're asking questions that go well beyond your original question and to some extent are off-topic for this site as they seem to be more about the math than programming. I don't know how you're simulating numerically – I'd suggest using a solver like `ode15s` to ensure that high frequency oscillations due to stiffness are captured properly. Yes, you can definitely try to linearize this about the numeric point that your simulation seems to be converging to. It may be an attracting/stable 3-D spiral equilibrium (describing equilibria in more than 2-D is often problematic).

Comment: Ok well I found that the system spirals around the equilibrium point. Is there a better way to solve for the steady state solution in this case? Instead of setting the derivatives to 0 - as they never really are 0 if spiralling.